# Can Conga Courier send reports generated by Conga QuickMerge?

Tags: email, reporting

I am working with reports generated by Conga QuickMerge. I need to send these reports using Conga Courier. Is this possible? if so, how?

Comment: Since these are both the same company, have you contacted them?

Comment: Robert Boyd from Conga, answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also Robert here, I work at Conga.  Conga Courier is only designed to deliver Salesforce Reports, not files generated by Conga QuickMerge.  However, Conga Conductor (more info here: http://www.congamerge.com/products/composer/add-ons#conductor) can batch and schedule the delivery of files generated by QuickMerge.  The scheduling component in both Courier and Conductor is exactly the same.

Conga Conductor is a paid add-on, but you can trial it 30 days for free to see if it fits your requirements.  Just get in touch with our support team or submit a free trial request (link here: http://pages.congamerge.com/conductor-free-trial-request) and we'll be glad to hook you up.

Hope this helps!

-Robert

Comment: You're very welcome! Could I ask a favor and have you vote up the answer?  Much appreciated!

Comment: I wish I could. I need a reputation of 15 to vote up. I am sorry, I am just starting on this.